# objective-c parameter variable - the color is red

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

In xcode when using the following:

```
friend:(NSString*)friend
```

friend is has the color red, like (id) is red - is friend a reserved word or something?

It work allright, it is just the editor that displays it as red?[image]

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCode is also an editor for C and C++; in C++ friend is a valid keyword.

Its worth mentioning that you can have C++ classes within an Objective-C project.

Comment: It's also a pretty bad sign that the compiler is treating that header like it's a CPP header, not a C/ObjC header.

Comment: Its worth a warning at least; if you had to convert your Obj-C class into C++ `friend` would become invalid as a variable name. Visual Studio does the same thing for `value` (due to it being a reserved word *only* in the scope of property and index setters).

Comment: @CodaFi: The problem is that most people use `'.h'` for C++ and ObjC++ headers, not just for C and ObjC headers. (And there's a good reason for this—in many cases, the same header file can actually be used from both C/ObjC and C++/ObjC++ code.) So, unless the IDE is going to refuse to allow that very common practice, it has to deal with the ambiguity. (The compiler is clearly not treating the header as C++, by the way, but as ObjC++, or it wouldn't have colored any of the ObjC syntax.)